# using JSON responses in dynamic tableview cells in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have an array of objects which I show on screen in tableview. Every object in array has URL property from which additional information can be obtained.

In my case it is array of Declarations and by sending GET request to its URL property I can get JSON with data about Declaration's date of issue.

I want to represent this date of issue in tableview cell. Where should I make a request?

- In `viewDidLoad` in `for-in` loop
- In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

I tried different approaches but always get only one response (not as many responses as `array.count`) and dozen of errors.

Please help and tell where to start from.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class DetailDeclarationInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let declarationInfoController = DeclarationInfoController()

    var declarationInfo: DeclarationInfo? {
        didSet {
            print("Received declarationInfo")
        }
    }

    var declarationModifiedDate: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
            print("New element in Dates")
            print(declarationModifiedDate)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let titleText = String((self.declarationInfo?.items.count)!)
        self.navigationItem.title = "Знайдено \(titleText) декларацій"

        guard let declarationInfo = declarationInfo else { return }
        for declarant in declarationInfo.items {

            declarationInfoController.fetchDeclarationDetails(with: declarant.id) { (declarationInfoElement) in
                if let declarationInfoElement = declarationInfoElement {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(declarationInfoElement)
                    print("Success!!")
                    self.declarationModifiedDate.append(declarationInfoElement["declarationType"] as! String)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let declarationInfo = declarationInfo {
                return (declarationInfo.items.count)
            } else {
                return 0
            }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "declarationInfoCell", for: indexPath)
        var personsPlaceOfWork: String = ""
        var date: String = ""

        if let placeOfWork = declarationInfo?.items[indexPath.row].placeOfWork {
            personsPlaceOfWork = placeOfWork
        }

        if (indexPath.row + 1) <= declarationModifiedDate.count {
            date = ", " + declarationModifiedDate[indexPath.row]
        }

        let cellText = (declarationInfo?.items[indexPath.row].lastname)! + " " + (declarationInfo?.items[indexPath.row].firstname)! + ", " + personsPlaceOfWork + date
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellText
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundPink

        return cell
    }
```

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} ["declarationYear1": 2016, "declarationType": 1] Success!! New element in Dates ["1"]

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. Make the request(s) in `viewDidLoad` not in `cellForRow`

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: in this example in console I have 5 elements in array, but only one has date in UI

Comment: Fetch the data in `DeclarationInfoController` with `DispatchGroup` to synchronize the API calls and pass the array to `DetailDeclarationInfoTableViewController` in the segue.

Comment: try  `responseString` instead of `responseJSON`

Comment: An error 3840 means your JSON input is invalid.

Comment: vadian, could You please give more detailed instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Reload Tableview after getting response and make the request from `viewdidload`. what kind of error did you get mention it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that after getting info for first object in array, the second response was that I exceeded the number of calls from IP(((